# Forms detail is being shown in URL for a POST request in react-express app

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs, express, https

I am making an user authentication server,however when creating an account for new user the details filled in the form are visible in the URL when the form is submitted,why?However data is also being added into the database.

My react frontend for that form is:

```
import {React,Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios'
import './form.css';

export default class signIn extends Component{
constructor(props){
super(props);
this.state={
 Name:'',
 Email:'',
 Password:'',
 ConfirmPassword:'',
 Response:''
}
this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
}
handleClick(e){
this.setState({
[e.target.name]:e.target.value
})
}
handleSubmit(e){
axios.post('http://localhost:5000/createUser',{
 Name:this.state.Name,
 Email:this.state.Email,
 Password:this.state.Password,
 ConfirmPassword:this.state.ConfirmPassword
 }).then((res)=>{
   this.setState({
     Name:'',
     Email:'',
     Password:'',
     ConfirmPassword:'',
     Response:res.data
   })
  }).catch((err)=>{
  console.log(err);
  })
 }
 render(){
 return (
<div>
<h5 className="message">{this.state.Response}</h5>
<div className="contact">
<section className="cntct">
<form >
 <input type="text" name="Name" placeholder="Enter Your Full Name" onChange={this.handleClick} value={this.state.Name} required/>
 <input type="email" name="Email" placeholder="Email Address" onChange={this.handleClick} value={this.state.Email} required/>
 <input type="password" name="Password" placeholder="Password" onChange={this.handleClick} value={this.state.Password} required/>
  <input type="password" name="ConfirmPassword" placeholder="Confirm Password" onChange={this.handleClick} value={this.state.ConfirmPassword} required/>
  <button className="logIn" onClick={this.handleSubmit}>Create Account</button>
   </form>
  </section>
  </div>
  </div>
 )
 }
}
```

My express backend has following code:

```
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
var sha1 = require('sha1');
var cors = require('cors')
const mySql = require('mysql');

const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT||5000

app.use(cors())
app.use(bodyParser.json())

//Database
const pool = mySql.createPool({
connectionLimit:1000,
host:'localhost',
user:'root',
password:'',
database:'nodejsauthentication'
})
//Creating New Accounts
function createUser(req,res,next){
if(req.body.Name ==""||req.body.Email ==""||req.body.Password==""||req.body.ConfirmPassword==""){
    res.send("All fields are necessary");
 }
else if(req.body.Password ==""||req.body.ConfirmPassword==""){
    res.send("Passwords donot match")
 }
else{
pool.getConnection((err,connection)=>{
if(err){
throw err;
 }
 else{
 connection.query(`SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE email='${req.body.Email}'`,(err,result)=>{
 if(err){
 throw err;
  }
  else if(result ==""){
  connection.query(`INSERT INTO USERS (name,email,password) VALUES('${req.body.Name}','${req.body.Email}','${req.body.Password}')`,(err,result)=>{
   connection.release()
    if(err){
    throw err
     }
    else{
     res.send("Sucessfully Created a User")
      }
     })
     }
     else{
     res.send("An user already exist with that email")
     }
    })
   }
  })
 }
}
//MiddleWare for logging In.
function authenticate(req,res,next)
{
pool.getConnection((err,connection)=>{
if(err) throw err
    
 connection.query(`SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE email='${req.body.Email}'`,(err,result)=>{
 if(err) throw err
 if(result =="")
 res.send("No user is associated with that email")

  else{
  connection.query(`SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE email='${req.body.Email}' AND password='${req.body.Password}'`,(err,result)=>{
  connection.release();
    
  if(err) throw err
  else{
  if(result =="")
  {
  res.send("Email or password Didnot Match");
  }
  else{
  res.send("Congratulations!!!")
     }
    }
   })
 }
})
     
})
 }

//requests
app.get('/',(req,res)=>{
res.send("At '/'");
})

app.post('/home',authenticate,(req,res)=>{
console.log("Recieved a post request");
 })

app.post('/createUser',createUser,(req,res)=>{
console.log("creating new Users");
})

//listen to a server
app.listen(PORT,()=>{
console.log(`Server running sucessfully at port ${PORT}`)
})
```

On form submission the input gets added to the backend however my URL changes to:
`http://localhost:3000/signIn?Name=harry&Email=gmail119%40gmail.com&Password=abcde12345&ConfirmPassword=abcde12345`

Comment: `button type="button"` try this